# synchronizing the live data write and read functionality

Tags: multithreading

One process_1 is writting the data1 and data2 every second in two different file.  The process_2 must send this data from this two files in out every second. Now thread_1 in process_2 will read the data and send out.
The problem faced by thread_1 is  either, it is reading the repeated information or the data sent out is not exactly every second.

Solution:
1.  Instead of thread_1 reading both file , spawn two threads. That way one data reading will not delay the other data.
2.  read both data into a que,  then read the data from this que using timer every second.

Can you let me know which solution would be better.

Implemented the solution#1  but  the problem with this is as the number of data to be read  increases,  number of read thread increases.

Comment: How are you writing to the file(s)?  Are you appending to the end?  Are you overwriting data that's already in the file?  If you're overwriting data, this is not a reliable way to pass data between processes.

Comment: @ Andrew Henle  - Data is overwritten to file.  It is how the design is I  donot have control on how data is written. I can only design on how best I can read the data.

Comment: That's a **bad** design.  How do you know the reading process(es) read a coherent chunk of data instead of half-old/half-new data?  There are multiple ways to pass coherent chunks of data between processes and/or threads.  Writing to a file with no synchronization between the writer(s) and reader(s) is not one of them.  You're supposed to make *that* work?  Just use a pipe, for example - write chunks of N bytes, and read those chunks.  Or shared memory and semaphores.